# How to check if a process is running on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, process

What I am trying to do it is a program to know if a process it is active on `Windows` to work with it in `Java`. I looked on the Internet and found two different solutions:

- [Option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005410/check-if-some-exe-program-is-running-on-the-windows)
- [Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318220/how-to-detect-via-java-whether-a-particular-process-is-running-under-windows)

But it is not at all what I am looking for.

According to the option 1, I would like a method to make reference to the process (and detect if it is active/running) but without searching in the full `tasklist` and then searching on it. I am searching if there is a direct method to do that.

I also though to add a filter to the tasklist but could not find any filter to only get the process I am looking for. I saw all the options using `tasklist /?` on my command line.

Then I searched information about the second option and `wmic` (that I never heard before) and it seems that `wmic` allows you to execute tasks on the command line (correct me if I am wrong please).

So, here I have two **questions**:

- Is there a direct method to know if a process is active on Windows with Java? Trying to avoid searching in the full tasklist or using `wmic`.
- If it is impossible, what of the two options that I put above would be better if we talk about efficient programming?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Java Native to import Process32Next() to enumerate processes. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9877993/1207195

Comment: Sounds like you are designing a complete bogus system here. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no direct way to query general processes as each OS handles them differently.
You kinda stuck with using proxies such as direct OS commands...

You **can** however, find a specific process using tasklist.exe with **/fi** parameter.
e.g: `tasklist.exe /nh /fi "Imagename eq chrome.exe"`
Note the mandatory double quotes.
Syntax & usage are available on [MS Technet site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx).

Same example, filtering for "chrome.exe" in Java:

```
String findProcess = "chrome.exe";
String filenameFilter = "/nh /fi \"Imagename eq "+findProcess+"\"";
String tasksCmd = System.getenv("windir") +"/system32/tasklist.exe "+filenameFilter;

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(tasksCmd);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

ArrayList<String> procs = new ArrayList<String>();
String line = null;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
    procs.add(line);

input.close();

Boolean processFound = procs.stream().filter(row -> row.indexOf(findProcess) > -1).count() > 0;
// Head-up! If no processes were found - we still get: 
// "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria."
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am going to try your code now but I have some questions. Do you use the `ArrayList` because the `BufferedReader` also returns the PID, name of console, etc...? And also, when you do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(tasksCmd);` if you already has the process running. Is it creates a new one? Thank you again!

Comment: OK with your code I could finally get it but I have one more question. What  it's the purpose for the last line of your code?: `Boolean processFound = procs...` If I ommit it the code works but if I put it my code gives to me an Exception so I think it is unnecesary. Is it?

Comment: It's Java8 only. You can replace with a standard for loop which looks for the required text.

Comment: The purpose of the last line is to check we didn't get "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.". (In this case the array has some content but it's not the required process).

Comment: Is it the same as put a throws Exception?

Comment: @Error404 - Join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102426/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-on-windows so we can check the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 9 you can do it like this:

```
Optional<ProcessHandle> processHandle = ProcessHandle.of(pid);
boolean isrunning = processHandle.isPresent() && processHandle.get().isAlive();
```

You are now also able, to get some info about the process directly with java.

```
Optional<ProcessHandle> processHandle = ProcessHandle.of(pid);
if(processHandle.isPresent()) {
 ProcessHandle.Info processInfo = processHandle.get().info();
 System.out.println("COMMAND: " + processInfo.command().orElse(""));
 System.out.println("CLI: " + processInfo.commandLine().orElse(""));
 System.out.println("USER: " + processInfo.user().orElse(""));
 System.out.println("START TIME: " + processInfo.startInstant().orElse(null));
 System.out.println("TOTAL CPU: " + processInfo.totalCpuDuration().orElse(null));

}
```

Comment: where do you get the pid? If you have the pid you already know that the process is running.

Comment: What is the difference between "isPresent()" and "get().isAlive()". Imo "isPresent()" is enough because it also returns false when the process is not alive. Any toughts?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be launching the process from the java instance. The advantages of this approach are that you can be fully sure that the process that is running, is the process you started. With tasklist, it is possible for normal users to start a process with the name as the target, or reuse the pid if the program closes.

For information how to start a process, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3774432/1542723) question.

> ```
> Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
> ```

You can then use the methods of Process to monitor the state of the program, for example `myProcess.exitValue()` blocks until the program is closed.

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I am looking for but trying to do it without execution the process by myself. I know that I have a process active and want to store it on a `Process` variable as you put on your example. Is it a way to do this but without geting all the array of process from the tasklist?

Comment: if the process launches another process and closes the other one there is no way of determining if it is alive. this method is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement such method easily using Java 9:

```
public boolean isProcessRunning(String processName)
{
    return ProcessHandle
        .allProcesses()
        .filter(p -> p.info().command().isPresent())
        .anyMatch(n -> n.info().command().orElse("").endsWith(processName));
}
```

**Note:** I used `endsWith(..)` because the command contains the full path of the executed file. BTW if you have the PID, look on the accepted answer.