# JNA process start time

Tags: java, process, jna

with this snippet from [JNA - Query Windows Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877993/jna-query-windows-processes) i have a list of my current running processes.

```
public class ListProcesses {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary(Kernel32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
        Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference processEntry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();          

        WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new WinDef.DWORD(0));
        try  {
            while (kernel32.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) {             
                System.out.println(processEntry.th32ProcessID + "\t" + Native.toString(processEntry.szExeFile));
            }
        }
        finally {
            kernel32.CloseHandle(snapshot);
        }
    } 
}
```

Is there a posiibility to get the start or running time of a process here?
In the API and the docs, I didn't found anything useful..