# Using JNI to call functions defined within a given DLL file

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio, dll, java-native-interface

My objective was to use JNI to access functions from kernel32.dll. As you can see below, I was doing pretty bad. I wrote down the whole procedure in the answer.

**Kernel32.java** :

```
package tn.kernel;

public final class Kernel32 {
    public static boolean loadKernel32(){
        System.loadLibrary("kernel32");
        return true;
    }

    public static native boolean K32EnumProcesses(int[] pProcessIds, int cb, int[] pBytesReturned);
}
```

**MainClass.java** :

```
package tn.kernel;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program started.");

        if(Kernel32.loadKernel32())
            System.out.println("Kernel32.dll loaded.");

        int n = 2000;
        int[] procs = new int[n];
        int ls = Integer.SIZE;
        int[] rs = new int[1];

        if(Kernel32.K32EnumProcesses(procs, ls * n, rs)){
            System.out.println("Success");
        }

        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

}
```

OUTPUT :

```
Program started.
Kernel32.dll loaded.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: tn.kernel.Kernel32.K32EnumProcesses([II[I)Z
    at tn.kernel.Kernel32.K32EnumProcesses(Native Method)
    at tn.kernel.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:15)
```

This the syntax for EnumProcesses :

```
BOOL WINAPI EnumProcesses(
  _Out_ DWORD *pProcessIds,
  _In_  DWORD cb,
  _Out_ DWORD *pBytesReturned
);
```

*If PSAPI_VERSION is 2 or greater, this function is defined as **K32EnumProcesses** in Psapi.h and exported in Kernel32.lib and Kernel32.dll. If PSAPI_VERSION is 1, this function is defined as **EnumProcesses** in Psapi.h and exported in Psapi.lib and Psapi.dll as a wrapper that calls **K32EnumProcesses**.* Source : *msnd.microsoft.com*

I tried with both K32EnumProcesses and EnumProcesses. Same results.

Comment: did you ever get loadKernel32 to return true?

Comment: @efekctive yes it did return true. you can see it wrote "Kernel32.dll loaded." in the output

Comment: yes. sorry. Have you tired run the jvm in verbose mode to see if there are any meaningful messages?

Comment: That's not the way `native` works; See the javah tool. With JNI, you define a service that your application demands and you write a DLL that provides it. The style you are using is more like [JNA](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32.html#Process32Next-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32-) (which uses JNI internally). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13478508/2226988)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creating a 64 bits Dynamic-Link Library for Windows

Prerequisites: Visual Studio

1/ Create a Visual Studio C++ project (ex: dllexample)

•   Select “Win32 Consol Application”

- Select “DLL”
- Select “Empty project”

2/ In “Solution explorer” right-click on “Header Files” > “Add” > “New Item…” > choose a name (ex: dllexample.h) > “Add”

•   Define the headers of your functions in “dllexample.h” this way:

```
__declspec(dllexport) <type> funcName(parameters…);
…
```

3/ In “Solution explorer” right-click on “Source Files” > “Add” > “New Item…” > choose a name (ex: dllexample.cpp) > “Add”

•   Use:

```
#include “dllexample.h”
```

•   Define the body of your functions (from the “dllexample.h” header file) in the “dllexample.cpp” source file:

```
<type> funcName(parameters…){
    //body instructions
}
```

•   In the upper toolbar select “x64”

•   Select “Build” > “Build Solution”

4/ Done

•   You can find “dllexample.dll” and “dllexample.lib” in “projects/dllexample/x64/Debug”

•   You can find “dllexample.h” in “projects/dllexample/dllexample”

### Calling a 64 bits DLL file (ex: dllexample.dll) from another 64 bits DLL or executable file on Windows

Prerequisites: “dllexample.dll”, “dllexample.lib” and “dllexample.h” or a precise functions description or guide and Visual Studio

1/ Create a Visual Studio C++ project (ex: dllcall)

•   Select “Win32 Consol Application”

- Select “DLL” to create a DLL file, “Consol Application” to create an executable file
- Select “Empty project”

2/ Copy “dllexample.dll”, “dllexample.lib” and “dllexample.h” to “projects/dllcall/dllcall”

3/ In “Solution explorer” right-click on “Header Files” > “Add” > “Existing Item…” > select ”dllexample.h” > “Add”

•   If you’re making a DLL file, create a new header file (ex: dllcall.h) in which you define the headers of your functions this way:

```
__declspec(dllexport) <type> funcName(parameters…);
…
```

4/ In “Solution explorer” right-click on “Source Files” > “Add” > “New Item…” > choose a name (ex: dllcall.cpp) > “Add”

•   Use:

```
#include “dllexample.h”
```

•   If you’re creating a DLL file, use:

```
#include “dllcall.h”
```

And then define the body of the functions (from the “dllcall.h” header file) in the “dllcall.cpp” source file. At the same time you can call functions from “dllexample.h”:

```
<type> funcName(parameters…){
    //body instructions
}
```

•   In the upper toolbar select “x64”

•   In “Solution explorer”, right-click on “dllcall” > “Properties” > “Linker” > “Input” > “Additional Dependencies” > “Edit” > add “dllexample.lib” (this option will be set only for the x64 debugger of the current Visual Studio project)

•   Select “Build” > “Build Solution” to generate the DLL and the Import Library (.lib) files, “Run” to generate the executable file and test it

5/ Done

•   You can find “dllcall.dll” and “dllcall.lib” or “dllcall.exe” in “projects/dllcall/x64/Debug”

•   You can find “dllcall.h” in “projects/dllcall/dllcall”

### Calling a 64 bits DLL file (ex: dllexample.dll) from a 64 bits Java program through JNI

Prerequisites: “dllexample.dll”, “dllexample.lib” and “dllexample.h” or a precise functions description or guide. Visual Studio, Eclipse with JNI plugin

1/ Create an Eclipse Java project (ex: dlltest)

2/ Create a class (ex: my.package.JNIClass)

•   Define methods headers as close as the functions definitions in “dllexample.h” using keywords:

```
public static final native <type> funcName(parameters..);
…
```

•   Run the project to generate “JNIClass.class”

3/ Open Command Line in folder “workspace/dllcall/src”

•   Generate “my_package_JNIClass.h” header file by running command:

```
javah my.package.JNIClass
```

4/ Create a 64 bits DLL file (ex: dllcall.dll) that calls “dllexample.dll” and includes “my_package_JNIClass.h”

•   In the “dllcall.cpp” source file, define the bodies of functions that are defined in the “my_package_JNIClass.h” header file

•   “my_package_JNIClass.h” includes “jni.h”,  to make it work, you must go to “Solution explorer” in Visual Studio and right-click on “Properties” > “Configuration Properties” > “C/C++” > “General” > “Additional Include Directories” > add the 64 bits “java/include” and “java/include/win32” paths (this option will be set only for the x64 debugger of the current Visual Studio project)

5/ Copy “dllcall.dll” and “dllexample.dll” to “workspace/dllcall/src”

•   In “Package explorer”, right-click on “dlltest” > “Properties” > “Java Build Path” > “Source” > expand “my/package/src” > select “Native Library Location” > “Edit” > add “my/package/src” as location path

•   Import the DLL files in “JNIClass.java” using:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary(“dllexample”);
    System.loadLibrary(“dllcall”);
}
```

6/ If the 64 bits JRE is not selected, then go to “Run” > “Run Configurations” > “JRE” > “Alternate JREs” > “Installed JREs” > put the 64 bits Java JDK directory (Should be something like: “C:\Program Files\Java \jdk”, while 32 bits Java JDK can be found in the “Program Files (x86)” folder

7/ Done

•   Now you can use the methods you defined in step 2